# Recreating price distribution chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, var

I'm trying to recreate following chart:

[image: Price chart]

Currently I have no idea what should I do now, wondering if there is a possibility to merge these charts or plot everything in one chart code,

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm



fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=6, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (0, 1), rowspan=6, colspan=1)
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


S = 5
T = 100
mu = 0
vol = 0.3

for i in range(10):

    daily_returns = np.random.normal(mu / T, vol / math.sqrt(T), T) + 1
    price_list = [S]

    for x in daily_returns:
        price_list.append(price_list[-1] * x)
    ax1.plot(price_list)
    ax1.set_ylim(0,10)



srange = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.01)
mean = 0
standard_deviation = 1

var = norm.pdf(srange, mean, standard_deviation)
ax2.plot(var,srange, color="grey")

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't under what you're asking.

Comment: ideas/tips how I can create following chart with matplotlib and python

Comment: I agree that it's not clear what you're asking here. The plot you produce resembles the shown plot already very well, so you need to be specific. Is it that you want the distribution to represent the actual data? Or is it the colors that don't match? Mind that you should ask a specific question here which can be answered. Stackoverflow questions are not meant to create some mindmapping on a vague problem.